# Issue labeling d3 sunburst

Tags: javascript, path, d3.js, label, sunburst-diagram

I am developing a d3 sunburst type.

Everything is ok, It is taking the flare JSON correctly but, when I go to label the path look what is happening:

[image]

The code is the following:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 700,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, radius]);

var hue = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#feec76","#aec7e8","#ff00bf","#7f7f7f"]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2 + 10) + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); });

d3.json("http://api.printoriente.com/treemap.php", function(error, root) {
  var g = svg.selectAll("g")
      .data(partition.nodes(root))
    .enter().append("g");

  var path = g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return hue((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
    .on("click", click);

  var text = g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")"; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
    .attr("dx", "6") // margin
    .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

And the rotation code is:

```
function computeTextRotation(d) {
  return (x(d.x + d.dx / 2) - Math.PI / 2) / Math.PI * 180;
}
```

This script works for all others d3 but I have to put those colors for each path.

Where is the problem?

Regards.

UPDATED: d3 sunburst with small font-size:

[image]

UPDATED: I want something like this:

[image]

UPDATED: Take a look of internal labels:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. Do you want the text to be coloured or is the spacing the issue?

Comment: The spacing between labels is the problem. I am saying that this code works in others d3 sunbursts but not in mine. Ignore it, my problem is with the labels.

Comment: Take a look of the imagen and see the labels T_T

Comment: That's because some of your slices are so small that the labels are too big. You could try to move the labels outside the sunburst, but your slices are so small that this is unlikely to help. Tooltips might be a better option.

Comment: It is not the problem. See the update, I put a smaller font-size and the issue continue.

Comment: Look at the slices. Some of them are very thin. There's no space to put labels there, regardless of font size.

Comment: I dont think that could be the problem. I tried with font-size 1px and It doesnt works.

Comment: What do you expect it to look like?

Comment: Look the new update. I want the labels like this.

Comment: Oh, just the position? You can adjust that using `text-anchor` and/or `dx`.

Comment: Ya, the labels' position. text-anchor? I am very newbie in d3, really, but i am very close to finish my project. Help me please.

Comment: Ok. Thats works for now. I changed on var text, dx .attr("dx", "6") for dx .attr("dx", "40"). but the problem with the label rotation continue. I have to rotate it 45° to the left aprox.

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://tributary.io/inlet/4127332/)?

Comment: Ok. It could take me some minutes to do it manually. Please wait a sec while i finish it to send you.

Comment: Ok. I finished It. You can see the image updated. Please, ignore the externals labels, take a look of internal labels (Creativo, No Etiquetado, Emprendedor and Creativo). The rest of labels are sons of the internal labels, I want all the labels in this positions with their children.

Comment: Could you post a complete working example please?

Comment: I can send you all the code and the JSON, if you want to create a simple html file. Ok?

Comment: Give me your email to send the code. Is easier, ok? Help me please I am desperate.

Comment: Can you put it on something like jsfiddle please?

Comment: Right. Look this http://jsfiddle.net/8k4F3/ and say me if it works please.

Comment: I will be right back in a second. I am at the office, going to my home. If you have an anwers please give me it.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8k4F3/1/) what you're looking for?

Comment: YEAH!!! Thats it!!! I am checking it at my phone... Let me check it at my laptop but thanks you very much!. What do you did? Please explain me.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got the code to calculate the angle from, but it seems to be completely off. If you look at [this example](http://tributary.io/inlet/4127332/), the code to compute the angle is (with everything else being equal)

```
var angle = (d.x + d.dx / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
```

Replacing the code in your example with that fixes the angles. To fix the positions, you can adjust the `dx` offset of the labels, e.g.

```
.attr("dx", 50")
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8k4F3/1/).